# Usuário comentou que problema foi resolvido mas não marcou como aceita a resposta, e agora?

Tags: debate

Possuo respostas que o usuário disse que resolveu o problema, mas não marcou como aceita. Tem como fazer com que isso ocorra?

Esse meu questionamento ocorre devido ao fato de que a pergunta marcada como aceita traz maior confiabilidade a quem entra no tópico.

Link de exemplo:

[Erro: cannot convert float* to float](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/20571/erro-cannot-convert-float-to-float/20574#20574)

Comment: Não tinha visto que já tinha pergunta semelhante. Obrigado @bfavaretto

Comment: De nada. Se achar que o que tem lá não responde sua dúvida, é só me avisar e podemos rever.